# Default PDF export location

Tags: qgis, export

I've set up quite a complex QGIS template in my firm to load up by default when creating a new QGIS project. Colleagues would save a copy of the project in it's proper place before conducting any work. The project is saved deep within our client filing structure in file explorer which I will now refer to as 'Project Home'.

After the mapping work was complete, exporting a layout to PDF/image would open file explorer automatically at 'Project Home' (as per Browser panel).

Recently, a colleague accidentally exported a layout before saving the QGIS template project as a new copy. They also managed to save the QGIS template after doing so. This means the convenience of QGIS automatically opening file explorer at the Project Home location when exporting is no longer, and instead by default opens where my colleague exported their PDF to.

I've since exported a PDF lower down in our filing structure and saved the QGIS project template but it's not quite as speedy as it once was.

Any ideas?

Comment: As per the [help/behavior] please do not include chit chat like thanks within your posts.